# My spring controller test doesn't enter controller

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockmvc

I am trying to test spring controller using mockMvc. There is existing functionality, so I referenced it as I was creating my test since I am new to spring controller. While existing test works fine, my test doesn't go into the spring controller I expected to. Here is my test:

```
@Test
    public void updatePriorityStudyDispatch() throws Exception {
        DispatchStudyPriorityRequest request = TestDataFactory.getDispatchStudyPriorityRequest();
        mockMvc.perform(post(BASE_URL, getDispatchId(WORKSTATION_ID_VALUE, STUDY_ID_VALUE))
            .accept(PowerShareMediaType.PSH_GATEWAY_STUDYDISPATCHER_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(gson.toJson(request)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
        verify(studyDispatcherService)
            .updatePriority(WORKSTAION_ID, STUDY_ID, TestDataFactory.getDispatchStudyPriorityRequest());
    }
```

and here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/{dispatchid}", produces = PowerShareMediaType.PSH_GATEWAY_STUDYDISPATCHER_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updatePriority(@PathVariable("dispatchid") String dispatchId,
        @Valid @RequestBody DispatchStudyPriorityRequest request) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I had a break points on my controller and it seems like it never enters it when I run the test. My result is 400 when I am expecting 200. I am not sure what is happening.

The one that is working basically have different "request" object (different model). Same BASE_URL, same ID_VALUEs, same MediaTypes. Here is controller

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{dispatchid}", produces = PowerShareMediaType.PSH_GATEWAY_STUDYDISPATCHER_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> dispatchStudy(@PathVariable("dispatchid") String dispatchId,
        @Valid @RequestBody StudyDispatchRequest request) {
```

I think it has something to do with RequestBody, but this is first time I am using RequestBody with some object. I learned that there is spring functionality that converts incoming Json file to object. However, I am really new to this concept, so it is hard for me to understand the issue.

Comment: if the result is 400, it should also have a message as to what is wrong

Comment: Well I used debugger and saw that it wasn't even going into the controller at all.

Comment: what i meant was - you can add log() in your mockMvc api call and see what the api is actually returning

Answer (score 0):

I found why it was happening. It was giving me 400 because Date() field in the DispatchStudyPriorityRequest object was in Gson format. Somehow Json format wasn't able to parse it correctly.

Gson format was something like "Jun 12, 2020" while Json format should have been "yyyy-mm-dd".